# Slow join performance in Postgresql with large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, indexing

I setup my Postgresql database using the following code, which will create 10 million records in test1 table, and test2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE test1(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    val text
);

CREATE TABLE test2(
    test1_id integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (test1_id) REFERENCES test1(id)
);

do $$
begin
for r in 1..10000000 loop
  insert into test1(id, val) values(r, 10000000-1);
  insert into test2(test1_id) values(r);
end loop;
end;
$$;

CREATE INDEX test1_val ON test1 USING btree(val);
```

Now I perform the following join:

```
SELECT * FROM test1 join test2 ON test1.id=test2.test1_id WHERE val='55555';
```

And the join takes more than 1 second to complete.

Here is the output of running explain on the query:

```
                                     QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=8.46..181757.13 rows=1 width=15)
   Hash Cond: (test2.test1_id = test1.id)
   ->  Seq Scan on test2  (cost=0.00..144248.48 rows=10000048 width=4)
   ->  Hash  (cost=8.45..8.45 rows=1 width=11)
         ->  Index Scan using test1_val on test1  (cost=0.44..8.45 rows=1 width=11)
               Index Cond: (val = '55555'::text)
(6 rows)
```

The example is more for illustrative purposes and in a real scenario there would be more attributes on the test2 table. Also in a real scenario there would likely be more records on test1, and test2, and the join would take longer to complete than 1 second.

Is there a more efficient way of structuring the indexes for this database, or performing the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to [index the foreign key](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/):

```
CREATE INDEX ON test2(test1_id);
```

Comment: Ah, that wasn't too smart of me! For some reason I though that adding the foreign key would automatically create an index.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. There are cases when you don't want the index, either because [it is never used](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) or because the table is too small.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I'm still getting slow join performance on my actual db but I'll try and raise another question which more accurately reflects the real database.

Comment: You should start a new question with the real query and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Interesting. On my DB server I was having the issues with slow queries and then I ran a `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and the query started running quickly afterwards.

Comment: That is coincidental. Perhaps autoanalyze or autovacuum processed a table in the mean time and improved the performance.